# Applying direct modification from GeometryEffect without using modifier function in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am looking to apply direct effect of modification of GeometryEffect without using `.modifier`, for understanding what i am looking for, look at this below codes, there is a **MyViewModifier** which is a `ViewModifier` and I am applying it via `.modifier` to a Text with approach number 1, and also you can see a function called `.myCustomViewModifier()` which do the same work without using `.modifier` in approach number 2.

I am looking the same job for **MyGeometryEffect**, as you can see I am applying **MyGeometryEffect** via using `.modifier`, now i want get same result without using the `.modifier`, therefore I made **MyCustomGeometryEffect** and `.myCustomGeometryEffect()`, but not sure how can make it possible!

I need help to apply GeometryEffect modification without using `.modifier`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ExampleView()
            
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                //.modifier(MyViewModifier())  // approach number 1
                .myCustomViewModifier()        // approach number 2
            
            Color.green
                //.modifier(MyGeometryEffect())  // approach number 1
                .myCustomGeometryEffect()        // approach number 2
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 100)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font.body.bold())
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}

struct MyCustomViewModifier<MyContent: View>: View {
    let content: () -> MyContent
    init(content: @escaping () -> MyContent) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        return content()
            .font(Font.body.bold())
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}

extension View {
    func myCustomViewModifier() -> some View {
        return MyCustomViewModifier(content:  { self } )
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MyGeometryEffect: GeometryEffect {
    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 0))
    }
}

struct MyCustomGeometryEffect<MyContent: View>: View {
    let content: () -> MyContent
    init(content: @escaping () -> MyContent) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        return content()
        // Now how can I apply wished GeometryEffect here without using .modifier ?

    }
}

extension View {
    func myCustomGeometryEffect() -> some View {
        return MyCustomGeometryEffect(content:  { self } )
    }
}
```

Comment: The `GeometryEffect` is-a `ViewModifier`, so can be applied only via `.modifier` (or `ModifiedContent`, which is the same)

Comment: I know it, as you see `ViewModifier` is a `ViewModifier` which can be applied only via `.modifier` but in second approach I showed a way to get the same result with another approach!  Looking same job for `GeometryEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, implementation of `GeometryEffect` is private (thus comparison in question is not accurate), so exactly we rather cannot replicate its behavior.

However for same specific cases something like the following can be used

```
struct MyCustomGeometryEffect<MyContent: View>: View {
    let content: () -> MyContent
    init(content: @escaping () -> MyContent) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        content()
          .projectionEffect(.init(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 0)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working, but I got confused with your comment and answer! Should I not using your answer? I mean is it safe using your answer? or apple does not want we use it?!

Comment: It is absolutely safe, just ... it does what it does, I would not think of it as full equivalence of GeometryEffect in common sense, because I did not see code of GeometryEffect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help, Is it possible that apple use `projectionEffect` with `CGAffineTransform` undercover for `.offset()` modifier? I have a strong feeling about it.